# HtmlTextWriter doesn't flush upon disposal?

Tags: c#, dispose, flush, htmltextwriter

I need to write some text with style (like color, fonts) so I decided to use html. I found that `HtmlTextWriter` is a class used for writing html file. However, I found that I must manually close or flush it otherwise nothing is written to the file. Why is it? (using statement should dispose it when the block is finished)

```
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StreamWriter(
            Path.Combine(EmotionWordCounts.FileLocations.InputDirectory.FullName, fileName),
            false, Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
            try
            {

                htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("html");
                htmlWriter.WriteLine();
                htmlWriter.Indent++;

                htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("body");
                htmlWriter.WriteLine();
                htmlWriter.Indent++;

                // write something using WriteFullBeginTag and WriteEndTag
                // ...

            } //try
            finally
            {
                htmlWriter.Indent--;
                htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("body");
                htmlWriter.WriteLine();

                htmlWriter.Indent--;
                htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("html");
                htmlWriter.Close(); // without this, the writer doesn't flush
            }
        } //using htmlwriter
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `HtmlTextWriter`.  You should make a self-contained test case and [report it using Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx).  It seems that `Close` and `Dispose` behave differently, which isn't documented and is extremely unusual.  I also can't find any documentation on MSDN stating whether the [HtmlTextWriter takes ownership of the underlying textwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8y8wst5.aspx) or not; i.e. will it dispose the underlying textwriter or must you?

**Edit 2:**  The MSDN page on [`HtmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) states that it inherits (as opposed to overrides) the virtual `Dispose(bool)` method.  This means the current implementation clearly *cannot* clean up with a using block.  As a workaround, try this:

```
using(var writer = ...make TextWriter...) 
using(var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer)) {

    //use htmlWriter here...

} //this should flush the underlying writer AND the HtmlTextWriter

// although there's currently no need to dispose HtmlTextWriter since
// that doesn't do anything; it's possibly better to do so anyhow in 
// case the implementation gets fixed
```

Incidentally, `new StreamWriter(XYZ, false, Encoding.UTF8)` is equivalent to `new StreamWriter(XYZ)`.  StreamWriter creates rather than appends by default, and it uses UTF8 without BOM by default as well.

Good luck - and don't forget to [report the bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx)!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps a lot. I just got some basic ideas about how to use it; I didn't write html before. But I am not familiar with the reporting thing. Maybe you should report this bug. (Or is it a feature?)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the try{} Finally {} block within the using statement as this will dispose of the object for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think for html document it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that HtmlTextWriter does not provide an override for TextWriter's `protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )` method to call `Close()` so, you're right, you'll need to do this yourself - TextWriter's implementation is empty. As aspect has pointed out, you don't need the `try finally` block within the `using` statement though. As Eamon Nerbonne has pointed out, this is surely a framework bug.

Comment: Thanks. I copied some code from a XMLTextWriter program, and I think it's a good idea to always WriteEndDocument. But it's not a big problem here I believe.